# check desired json key (not value) exist in the parsed json response in golang

Tags: json, go, parsing

lets say i have a json response like this, as you can see sometimes email exists sometimes not.
now i need to check the email key exists or not and pretty print the json response accordingly.
how can i do this?

```json
[
  {"name" : "name1", "mobile": "123", "email": "email1@example.com", "carrier": "carrier1", "city", "city1"},
  {"name" : "name2", "mobile": "1234", "carrier": "carrier2", "city", "city2"}
  ...
]
```

here i need to check the p.Email exists or not, if it exists assign the email value if not assign empty string

```golang
for i, p := range jsonbody.Data {
                        
                        a := p.Name
                        b := p.Phone[i].Mobile
                        c := p.INTaddress[i].Email  // here i need to check 
                        d := p.Phone[i].Carrier
                        e := p.Address[i].City
                          
                         ..........

}
```

i tried searching but not found any answers for golang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here i need to check the p.Email exists or not, if it exists assign the email value if not assign empty string

Note that when you define the field as `Email string` and the incoming JSON provides *no* `"email"` entry then the `Email` field will remain an empty string, so you could simply use that as is. No additional checks necessary.

If you want to allow for `null` use `Email *string` and simply use an `if` condition to check against `nil` as suggested by 072's answer.

And when you need to differentiate between undefined/null/empty use a custom unmarshaler as suggested in the answer below:

```golang
type String struct {
    IsDefined bool
    Value     string
}

// This method will be automatically invoked by json.Unmarshal
// but only for values that were provided in the json, regardless
// of whether they were null or not.
func (s *String) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    s.IsDefined = true
    if string(d) != "null" {
        return json.Unmarshal(d, &s.Value)
    }
    return nil
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/gs9G4v32HWL

Then you can use the custom `String` instead of the builtin `string` for the fields that you need to check whether they were provided or not. And to do the checking, you'd obviously inspect the `IsDefined` field *after* the unmarshal happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer, then check against `nil`:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
)

var input = []byte(`
[
  {"name" : "name1", "mobile": "123", "email": "email1@example.com", "carrier": "carrier1", "city": "city1"},
  {"name" : "name2", "mobile": "1234", "carrier": "carrier2", "city": "city2"}
]
`)

type contact struct {
   Name string
   Email *string
}

func main() {
   var contacts []contact
   json.Unmarshal(input, &contacts)
   // [{Name:name1 Email:0xc00004a340} {Name:name2 Email:<nil>}]
   fmt.Printf("%+v\n", contacts)
}
```